# Enforcing element values in xml schema for a list

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I have the following elements (excuse the syntax) :-

```
<xs:complexType name="shop_T">
  <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="other_info" type="other_info_T" />
</xs:complexType>
```

Now I wish to refer to this complexType in two ways

```
<xs:element name="list_shops_in_city">
  <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="shop" type="shop_T" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="order">
  <xs:element name="shop" type="shop_T" />
</xs:element>
```

Can I enforce the constraint that if shop_T is used in a city-wide shop list, the value of it's child element "city" should be the same as that of the list itself. And if it is used by itself, then city can be anything. ?

If this can't be done with XML Schema, then is there another way to do it using a standard validating technology (say using DTDs. I am only familiar with XML Schema so can I get this done by reading up another technology)? Or do I need to code this up in my application logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using XML Schema, but only by using the new assertions facility in XSD 1.1 which became a Recommendation a couple of weeks ago: XSD 1.1 support is available in Xerces and Saxon.

Comment: This sounds like what I need. Do you know if this is supported in xerces-c? I couldn't find any evidence of the same...